# Control a robotic gripper

Tags: control, robotic-arm

I have created a robotic gripper. However, I need help in the control circuit:

[image: Control schematic]

There are two buttons, the upper and lower one (connected to the timer):

- the upper one is two states timer either up or down (will be replaced with an active low pin in PCB design).
- the lower one is a push button that must be pushed and  let back to its initial position to give a pulse to the monostable timer to make the servo rotate long enough to just close the gripper (calculate with the RC circuit).

My problem: I want to replace the down button with some component so as to give a quick pulse when the upper button change state.

For example, the button was 0 and went 1 -> Component -> a small pulse to drive the timer (not a pulse that will last until the state changes):

[image: Timing diagram]

Where,

- Green: is button state
- Red: trigger pulse needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with a 555 timer, or even a flip flop and a counter.   Are you looking for design concepts or a detailed design?

EDIT

Check out [this site](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/monostable.html) for a simple edge-triggered one-shot that uses two nor gates and an R-C (scroll down to the *NOR Gate Monostable* section).   I can't draw the circuit on here using my phone so I apologize about just providing a link.

Comment: Detailed if possible.

Comment: Thanks, actually I totally forgot about edge triggering. I am gonna use this https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/04190.png  I hope it can be simulated on proteus.

Comment: How to implement both negative and positive edge triggering in the same circuit

Comment: Use a NOT gate and replicate your one-shot.

Comment: Thanks so much SteveO for your help. Wish you all the good luck.